# Discord.py 'Channel Object has no attribute create_ytdl_player

Tags: python, discord

Good evening, everyone. I'm currently writing a Discord bot for my friends and I to play music from YouTube URL's in our voice channel. I've been going off of discord.py's API reference to create it, but I'm facing an annoying error. Upon runtime, I see this:

```
AttributeError: 'Channel' object has no attribute 'create_ytdl_player'
```

I also do have the youtube-dl module installed. Below is my complete code. Thank you for any comments.

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.ext.commands import Bot
import asyncio
import random

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')

@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def play(ctx):

voice = ctx.message.author.voice.voice_channel
await bot.join_voice_channel(voice)

url = 'some_url'
player = await voice.create_ytdl_player(url)

bot.run(NO TOKEN 4 U)
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you're calling the `create_ytdl_player` method on the wrong object. Instead of calling it on `voice`, you want to be calling it on the return value of the asynchronous call you make to `bot.join_voice_channel`.

[The API reference](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.VoiceClient.create_ytdl_player) shows it like this:

```
voice = await client.join_voice_channel(channel)
player = await voice.create_ytdl_player('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d62TYemN6MQ')
player.start()
```

But the `voice` variable in the example means something different than what it does in your code. Your `voice` is equivalent to the example code's `channel`.

Try something like this, with some new variable names:

```
voice_channel = ctx.message.author.voice.voice_channel
voice_client = await bot.join_voice_channel(voice_channel)

url = 'some_url'
player = await voice_client.create_ytdl_player(url)
```

You probably need to call `start` on the player as well.